# How to install the salesforce python library from github

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I downloaded the simple-salesforce zip file from github because i want to connect to salesforce using python. I am a bit lost how to install  the library.
I am just used to doing pip install but have never really manually downloaded a package and installed it. How should I go about it?
Assuming I want to install the version in github and not pypi.org.

Comment: Have you tried typing `pip install simple-salesforce==0.3` or `python pip install simple-salesforce==0.3` into the command-line?

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming you have used `git clone somerepo.git`

Navigate into somerepo. There you should see some files including `setup.py` and/or a folder called `dist` which contains `.whl` and/or `.tar.gz` files

If you are using `setup.py`, you can use

```
python setup.py install
```

Which should install the package for you. Otherwise, if you are using a wheel or tarball in `dist` you can pip install that wheel using

```
python -m pip install dist/file.tar.gz`
```

or

```
python -m pip install dist/file.whl
```